# My SWIPER JS simply won't load/work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, swiper.js

A website I am writing worked in Chrome, Firefox, Android etc. but failed when I tested on an iPad (Safari), so I narrowed down to the following code to test. Swiper JS is the culprit, at least for me. I added the external JS to see if Safari wasn't loading the linked files, like a CORS issue I researched, but it is. The external function green() simply changes the background color.

On all my browsers, the swiper works and the background ends up green; on Safari, changes to red (so clearly JS works) and the swiper does not initialize!

Tested on localhost, 10.0.0.26, and even copied over to a domain on Bluehost. Same thing all cases. I already grabbed the latest copy of SwiperJS since I was several behind; does not make a difference.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="swiper.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <style>
        .x {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .test {
            width: 80%;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = init;

        function init() {

            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

            var aSwiper = new Swiper('.test', {
                centeredSlides: true,
                effect: 'coverflow',
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                coverflowEffect: {
                    rotate: 0,
                    slideShadows: false,
                    depth: 200,
                    stretch: 0
                },
                spaceBetween: 25
            });


            green();

        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="swiper test">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper ">
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
            <div class='swiper-slide x'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

addition: Using something called 'Inspect' was able to start debugging the iPad on my Windows machine, yay, and console comes up with "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name." on line 2456 of swiper.js
Unfortunately this is beyond my current capabilities to reverse-engineer but may help you guys...

Comment: is ` '...'` literally the error? Seems whatever version of safari you got there doesn't understand spread or rest syntax - but that's been available in Safari since version 8 in 2014 (except for spread in object literals since 11.1 in 2018) - I guess the question is, what version of Safari

Comment: Wow, is it that simple??!! I got an old iPad from a neighbor just to test my sites; I've never been an Apple guy. I'll try to find the version now; upgrading is more difficult since I forgot my password and Apple seems not to send instant resets even after confirming identity!

Comment: NOPE. iPad says iOS version 10.3.3 and Internet says "...Safari version will be the same."

Comment: see how I said `except for spread in object literals since 11.1` which is AFTER 10.3.3 and the line of code is likely `c.loopFix({ ...loopParams,` - your Safari is too old to work with that code

Comment: the most telling document in swiper is [browserlistrc](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/.browserslistrc) which shows that it's compatible with `Safari >=15` - clearly swiper is written to only support modern browsers - seems it's never supported `Safari < 11` either

Comment: Thanks; apparently never checked their compatibility. I'm not a JS guru but seems I can replace their spread operation with "Object.assign" however does not work inside an object literal like they use the spread. Is there an alternative? Can I simply replace the spread with each of the object's properties? Or does spread literally put in the _current property values..?

Comment: No idea, that's a big file, the spread operator is used many times. The fact that the author states swiper is made for modern browsers suggests this one incompatibility may be the tip of the iceberg for you though - there's probably a host of CSS that won't work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256434/discussion-between-uri613-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Jaromanda X and my own further debugginging, seems that their code uses (at least) the spread operator, unsupported in older versions of Safari. Period. Bummer. Thanks for all your help!